# Using JimiMultiImageRasterDecoder

Tags: java, tiff

How do I use the abstract class `JimiMultiImageRasterDecoder`?  [Javadoc here](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/xmltools/formatters/fop/Jimi/docs/html/api/com/sun/jimi/core/JimiMultiImageRasterDecoder.html)

Is there a(n anonymous) subclass?  Or will I definitely have to roll my own implementation (something I'd rather avoid, but will do if necessary).

Background: reading multi-page TIFF files.  Can't use JAI due to access/permissions restrictions.  If there's an easier way to do this, I'll be happy to try it.